# NodeJS OAuth2 CORS issue with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, oauth-2.0, cors

I've been trying a ton of things found on the internet for the past 6 hours and I can't seem to solve this.

1. I have a local testing Angular app, under http://tok.client
2. I have FrankHassanabad's OAuth2orize Recipes (https://github.com/FrankHassanabad/Oauth2orizeRecipes) under `http://localhost:3000`

For the life of me, I can't make a request to the OAuth2 server for a token.

**Client Side Code:**

`.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {
        //Reset headers to avoid OPTIONS request (aka preflight)
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {};
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
        console.log($httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain);
        console.log($httpProvider.defaults.headers.common);
    })`

```
$scope.doLogin = function() {
            console.log('DUMMY - doLogin');
            return $http.post('https://localhost:3000/oauth/token', 'grant_type=password&username=bob&password=secret&scope=offline_access',{
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'Basic YWJjMTIzOnNzaC1zZWNyZXQ',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://localhost:3000',
                        'Accept': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    }
                }
            )
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    // this callback will be called asynchronously
                    // when the response is available
                })
                .error(function(dataX, status, headersX, config) {
                    console.log(dataX);
                    console.log(status);
                    console.log(headersX);
                    console.log(config);
                    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                    // or server returns response with an error status.
                });


            //fetchService();

        };
```

**Server Side Code**

```
//Session Configuration
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Accept, Authorization, Content-Type');
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
        res.send(200);
    } else {
        next();
    }

},express.session({
    secret: config.session.secret,
    store: sessionStorage,
    key: "authorization.sid",
    cookie: {maxAge: config.session.maxAge }
}));
```

I tried to add all the CORS proper functioning requirements, that I could find, and it is not working.

This is the response I get in my browser: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zcujugh2m4i0xml/Screenshot%202014-03-26%2000.46.51.png

I don't even see the header I set in the provisional headers, I read a ton of articles and stackoverflow questions, I just can't figure it out.

At some point I though it was some sort of https issues, but I have https locally and the OAuth2 demo is working flawlessly, The REST Console in Chrome is also working wonderfully, only AngularJS decided to make me spend a lot of hours trying to fix this :).

What could be the issue?

Comment: Apparently by using the info from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome/6083677#6083677    ... Disabling Chrome's Security I can make the post successfully. This isn't a fix, but for the current testing purposes it works, now I just have to see how make it work in cordova's web-worker.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that going to help, but it looks like you are trying to use the password grant type. This grant type requires knowledge or the user credentials as well as the OAuth2 client credentials (you exchange all of these for an access token).

That grant is not meant to be used client side because that would mean leaking your OAuth consumer credentials to everyone. In JavaScript you add an Authorization header to your request with value "Basic YWJjMTIzOnNzaC1zZWNyZXQ". That's just your client credentials base64 encoded (so decoded it's abc123 / ssh-secret).

For client-side (i.e. JavaScript) applications, the implicit grant flow (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.2) is usually recommended.

There are some Angular libraries that support it: e.g. https://github.com/enginous/angular-oauth.

(I have not tried using these libraries so I can't vouch for them)